# Can I connect to bluetooth devices using UWP apis without packaging app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to use nice UWP bluetooth classic APIs in my app. However my app has to be used as .exe, and it has to be portable (no installation in system). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API used by UWP comes from the Windows Runtime Api, if you need to integrate Windows Runtime API in your desktop application, this is feasible.

Here is the document: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

But there are still some restrictions:

1. Due to the reference to the corresponding version of the SDK, your application can only run on the corresponding version (and above) of the Windows 10 system. May not work properly on lower version systems.
2. According to the description of [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api), the Bluetooth API in Runtime is not yet fully supported in desktop applications.

---

In the description, you mentioned that you want to use portable application. Although many application functions can only be used in applications with a package identity, `Windows.Device.Bluetooth` is not listed here.

If the class under the `Windows.Device.Bluetooth` namespace has the **Windows.Foundation.Metadata.DualApiPartition** attribute, it means that the class can also be used directly in desktop applications, you can view related APIs in the [`Windows.Device.Bluetooth` document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice?view=winrt-19041).